# chart js with angular2 loading dynamic data only after zoomin

Tags: angular, chart.js

I am working on an angular 2 application with chartjs to show some data using pie, doughnut.

I am able to render the chart with static data but it is not working with dynamic data. It renders the dynamic data only after zoomin.

Could you please assist me solve this and help render the data dynamically in one go.

component html:

```
<canvas baseChart 
          [data]="getDoughnutChartData()"
          [labels]="getDoughnutChartLabels()"
          [colors]="lineChartColors"
          [chartType]="doughnutChartType"
          [legend]="legend"></canvas>
```

component ts file:

```js
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { PaymentModeServiceComponent } from '../../services/paymentmode/paymentmode-service.component';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { PaymentMode } from '../../domain/paymentmode';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-paymentmode',
  templateUrl: './paymentmode.component.html',
  providers: [PaymentModeServiceComponent]
})
export class PaymentModeComponent {

   paymentModes: Array<PaymentMode> = [];
   
         // Doughnut
  private doughnutChartLabels:string[]=["sdsd"];
  doughnutChartData:number[]=[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1 ];
  public doughnutChartType:string = 'doughnut';

  
  public lineChartColors:Array<any> = [{
                backgroundColor: [
                "#0000ff",
                "#ff0000",
                "#00ff00",
                "#728885",
                "#f98885",
                "#f9fc4b"
  ]}
            ];
            
   public legend:boolean = false;
  
   constructor(dataService: PaymentModeServiceComponent) {
    dataService.getPaymentModes().subscribe(
          paymentMode => this.paymentModes = paymentMode,
      );
  }
  
  
  getDoughnutChartLabels() {
   for (let i = 0; i < this.paymentModes.length; i++) {
    let paymentMode = this.paymentModes[i];
    this.doughnutChartLabels[i] = paymentMode.paymentMode;
   }
   return this.doughnutChartLabels;
   }
   
   getDoughnutChartData() {
   for (let i = 0; i < this.paymentModes.length; i++) {
    let paymentMode = this.paymentModes[i];
    this.doughnutChartData[i] = paymentMode.paymentModeTotalSales;
   }
   
   //this.doughnutChartData.splice(this.doughnutChartLabels.length + 1, this.doughnutChartData.length - this.doughnutChartLabels.length);
   
   //this.doughnutChartData = this.doughnutChartData.slice();
   
   return this.doughnutChartData;
   }
  

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have come across this problem with Angular 2 and many charting packages and generally what I have had to do is along the following lines:

(1) Bind to a collection that has not been instantiated

```
HTML: [data]="doughnutChartData" ; TS: doughnutChartData:number[]
```

(2) add an ngif to your chart markup e.g.

```
<canvas baseChart  *ngIf="doughnutChartData && doughnutChartData.length > 0" ....>
```

(3) On ng init run your `getDoughnutChartData` function. use a local collection in you `getDoughnutChartData` function to collect the data. when the data has returned/completed do `doughnutChartData = localDoughnutChartData`

Using the `ngif` means no attempt is made to render the chart until you have the data

You can add a DIV above it which contains a spinner and has the opposite ngif so a spinner is shown while the chart data is made e.g. `*ngIf="!doughnutChartData  || doughnutChartData.length < 1"`

Comment: it worked for me. Thanks a lot. key was ngif and ngoninit.

Answer (score 0):

This works like a charm

```
  <canvas *ngIf="doughnutChartData && doughnutChartData.length > 0" baseChart
  [data]="doughnutChartData"
  [labels]="doughnutChartLabels"
  [chartType]="doughnutChartType"
  [options]="barChartOptions"></canvas>
```